# How can I obtain a transposed UNION of 3 SQL Tables?

Tags: sql, t-sql, union, transpose

How can I obtain a transposed UNION of the TSQL Query Results below

```
SELECT TOP 1 Column_A FROM table1

SELECT TOP 1 Column_B FROM table2

SELECT TOP 1 Column_C FROM table3
```

So that the output will be ONE row of 3 columns with a single value per each:

```
[Column_A] [Column_B] [Column_C]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
Select 
 (SELECT TOP 1 Column_A FROM table1) as 'Column_A',
 (SELECT TOP 1 Column_B FROM table2) as 'Column_B',
 (SELECT TOP 1 Column_C FROM table3) as 'Column_C'
```